# dotNetRDF VS Jena.NEt VS others with Dotnet ?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, jena, dotnetrdf

what is the most common tool used for Reading & Writing RDF and Querying with Sparql with different end points .
so far i've found

- Jena (jena.net) :  it's developed for Java but some people managed to   convert it to Assemblies
- DotnetRDF

i wonder if there are others and which one is best to use what the the pros and cons  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best answer i've found in [Answers.semantiweb](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109141444/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/14227/jena-net-and-other-semantic-web-tools)

> Give a try to dotNetRDF.
>
> I have been used it in one of my projects and I am satisfied with it.
>
> It is SPARQL-capable, supports both local and remote queries and, the
>   most important, it is actively maintained

i've started using dotnetRDF the creator also have left a good documentation on the website 
http://www.dotnetrdf.org/

and a [good tutorials](http://dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Projects/ProjectSummary.aspx?pid=6) as well

Answer (score 5):

Both of the above are good. Other ones include:

[Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) - Java covering RDF, SPARQL, OWL. Actively developed

[Redland, Raptor Rasqal](http://librdf.org/) - C & Ruby, covers everything, actively    developed

[ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki) - PHP, RDF, SPARQL, no longer activel developed

You've also got a lot of supporting frameworks for things like ORDFM that build off the above namely:

[Jenabean](http://code.google.com/p/jenabean/)

Empire

[AliBaba](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-beta3/)

[RDFReactor](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/RDFReactor)

RDFBean

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for .Net specifically, there is also [dotSesame](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dotsesame/), which is an IKVM-port of the (Java-based) [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) framework.

Answer (score 1):

dotnetRdf Provides a suite of command line and GUI tools for working with RDF and SPARQL, you can find links to their documentation.Visit the link below...
https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Tools

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try RDFSharp at Microsoft Codeplex (http://rdfsharp.codeplex.com/).